# How to correctly handle responses to async requests in the view model?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have a local mock-repository that returns the result in the format Result<List>.The result may or may not be successful. In addition, I have a viewmodel, and a fragment with a ListView and a TextView How to properly process this result in the view model and display it in the fragment? That is, in case of a successful answer, I show the list in ListView, and in case of failure, I show TextView with error message. The question is exactly how to process an object of type Result<List>

Sorry for the possibly stupid question, I'm just learning :)

Edited: Sorry for this misleading wording. My question is how to properly process the result of the getAuthors function? How can I handle the situation when Result.Failure happens?

```
suspend fun getAuthors(): Result<List<Author>> {
        randomDelay()
        return randomResult(
            listOf(
                Author(
                    authorIds[0],
                    "Author One"
                ),
                Author(
                    authorIds[1],
                    "Author Two"
                ),
            )
        )
    }
```

```
private suspend fun randomDelay() {
        delay((100L..1000L).random())
    }

    private fun <T> randomResult(data: T): Result<T> =
        if ((0..100).random() < 5) {
            Result.failure(RuntimeException())
        } else {
            Result.success(data)
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit open-ended and vague. What are you trying to accomplish? What have you done? Where are you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Have you read the Android Architecture documentation?

Comment: Sorry for this misleading wording. My question is how to properly process the result of the getAuthors function? How can I handle the situation when Result.Failure happens?

Comment: How to handle failure is dependent on your app.

Comment: I need at least some sample on how it's done with the Result class

Comment: OK. Which `Result` class are you using? Did you make your own? Using a library?

Comment: Kotlin.Result class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need at least some sample on how it's done with the Result class

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    val result = getAuthors()
    
    if (result.isFailure) {
        // Handle Failure
    }
    else {
        // Handle success
    }

    // OR
    result.onFailure { exception ->
        // Handle Failure
    }.onSuccess { value ->
        // Handle success
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! But how can i take data(list) from result?

Comment: Use any of the `getXXX` functions that make the most sense for your case. 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/
Or the `value` object in my `onSuccess` example.